How to retrieve Vendor Bill ID by Purchase Order ID using NetSuite REST API?
I am working with the NetSuite REST API and need to retrieve the Vendor Bill ID associated with a specific Purchase Order ID. I have the Purchase Order ID, and I would like to query the API to obtain the related Vendor Bill's ID (at least).
I have already tried searching the documentation, but I am struggling to figure out the correct endpoint or method to use for this purpose.
Does anyone have an example or guidance on how to retrieve the Vendor Bill ID by using the Purchase Order ID in the NetSuite REST API?
I have explored the NetSuite REST API documentation and tried using the GET /record/v1/purchaseOrder/{id} endpoint to retrieve the Purchase Order details. However, I was unable to find a direct way to retrieve the associated Vendor Bill ID. I also tried looking for related records by querying the vendorBill resource, but I couldn't establish a clear relationship between the Purchase Order and Vendor Bill in the API responses.
I was expecting to find an endpoint or method that would allow me to retrieve the Vendor Bill ID associated with a specific Purchase Order ID, ideally through a simple API call or a related field in the Purchase Order record.

For this, you will require to create a custom restlet script in NetSuite. The script will contain the above logic mentioned by you.
The restlet script can be coded in the 'GET' part. The design would include fetching the Purchase Order ID (which you will be passing via 3rd party application), fetching the Vendor Bills associated with this Purchase Order ID, and returning the values.
Let me know if you require more details or if you have any concerns.

To achieve this, you'll need to create a Restlet script in NetSuite. With this search you should handle the logic to fetch the Vendor Bill ID associated with a specific Purchase Order ID, here is an example:
var vendorbillSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "vendorbill",
   filters:
   [
      ["type","anyof","VendBill"], 
      "AND", 
      ["createdfrom.type","anyof","PurchOrd"], 
      "AND", 
      ["createdfrom.number","equalto","XXXXXXXXXXX"] 
      "AND", 
      ["mainline","is","T"]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({name: "trandate", label: "Date"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "tranid", label: "Document Number"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "entity", label: "Name"})
   ]
});
var searchResultCount = vendorbillSearchObj.runPaged().count;
log.debug("vendorbillSearchObj result count",searchResultCount);
vendorbillSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
   // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
   return true;
});

